# Error 403: Access not configured. API does not appear in Google Cloud Console

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

I created a Google cloud endpoint API in java:

```
@Api(name = "myAPI",
     version = "v1",
     namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "endpoints",
                                ownerName = "endpoints",
                                packagePath=""))
public class MyEndpoint {

    /** Déclaration de la méthode  */
    @ApiMethod(
            name = "getPeople",
            path = "getPeople/{name}",
            httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public People getPeople(@Named("name") String name)  {

        People pers  = ObjectifyDAO.getByKey(People.class, name);

        return pers;
    }
```

The API appears in the API explorer https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/ but it does not appear in the google cloud console api dashboard
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=myproject&duration=PT1H

When i make a request with the following code:

```
var init = function() {
  var rootApi = 'https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/';
  var apiKey = "qsfqfdsqzM8TICqjJR29BcXWfLTvradadcqsd";

  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);

  gapi.client.load('myAPI', 'v1', function() {
      console.log("myAPI api loaded");
      gapi.client.myAPI.getPeople({name:"Buddha"}).execute(function(resp)               {
            console.log(resp);
        });
  }, rootApi);
  // Appeler l'api todos

    }
```

I get "Access Not Configured.  has not been used in project 123456 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting the google cloud console then retry."

But nothing appears but the native Google APIs on the google cloud console api dashboard.

Any ideas on how to enable it or solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `Endpoints Frameworks` and if so, have you [deployed your API configuration](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/test-deploy)?

Comment: Thank you. I have now deployed my API configuration and the API appears in the google cloud console api dashboard. But there is still the same issue  [(screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6sTfCjset_JLU5JWi1YellsSHM/view?usp=sharing), my guess is there is two different API services and my calls do not connect with the right one, why ?

Comment: It seems somewhere in your configuration you have set `pesonnagesApi` instead of `unijob-dev.appspot.com`.

Comment: Thank you. Finally got it working using maven, following strictly the google tutorial and 100% without Eclipse (which i'm sure avoid issues)

Answer (score 0):

I used maven this time following strictly the google tutorial and 100% without Eclipse and got it to work. Here are the steps i did:

- install maven
- create an empty folder for the project
- add src/main/ folder containing java folder and webapps as following https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend/src/main
- add a pom.xml file to the root folder with the following content https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend/pom.xml
- open a terminal at the root folder run these commands in order:

  1. mvn clean package
  2. run mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs
  3. gcloud endpoints services deploy target/openapi-docs/openapi.json
  4. mvn appengine:deploy